# question regarding the NSString unacceptance

Tags: iphone

how to  resolve this error??

[NCFArray length];
acception

Comment: We'd need to see the code that caused it to help you

Answer (score 1):

If you're working with an array, you may be looking for `[theArray count]` rather than `[theArray length]`.

Otherwise you are somehow using an array where you mean to use a string - how do you define/where do you get your NSString from?